# too may initializers in struct array?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct  Marker
{
static int self_unum;
static  int mark_unum;
static  bool is_marking;
static  int last_mark_cycle;
};
static Marker Team[11]={ {0,0,false,0} };
```

error:
 /home/d/Documents/alice/src/Miracle_Mark_System.cpp:32: error: too many initializers for 'Marker'
 static Marker Team[11]={ {0,0,false,0} };
                                        ^
                                        ^

```
                                    ^
```

Comment: Why is everything static? This makes no sense.

Comment: my project need  static num to  save  it  history  data

Comment: @user5244032 If you need static data, then by all means use it, but remember that every instance of `Marker` will share it. Properties of individual `Marker` instances should be instance members (not static). Also, I would suggest sticking to one naming convention (i.e. don't mix and match CamelCase and underscore_case). Plus if you're using capitalised class/struct names, don't use capital letters for variables. An array of type `Marker` representing teams should probably be called `teams` (note lowercase `t` and pluralised `s` suffix).

Answer (score 4):

The `static` keyword is used to define class, as opposed to instance, members. This means they are symbols not attached to any specific instance of `Marker`, and accessed using the syntax `ClassName::classMember` (e.g. `Marker::self_unum`), as opposed to `instanceName.instanceMember` (e.g. `Team[0].self_unum`).

So `Marker` itself is a struct with no fields, that's why you get the error.

Remove the useless `static` keyword from the field declarations:

```
struct  Marker
{
  int self_unum;
  int mark_unum;
  bool is_marking;
  int last_mark_cycle;
};
```

Comment: You still can access static members through objects. (As in `instanceName.instanceMember`.